# form validation through javascript - error alert coming but saving the data

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

here I am comparing the location name whether its already entered or not, In my code I am getting alert when I click submit button but also data submitted. onchange function not working as I expected, can anyone help me how stop the data not submitting when I get alert?
When submitting time validation should be done, why because in our test server we are getting some delay after click button, so only data submitting after alert also. do you have any idea on this? Thanks in advance

```
 <form class="form-inline" id="desgForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="../locationSubmit.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" id="locationName" autocomplete="off"  name="locationName"  class="form-control validate[required]" onchange="desgCheck();" onkeyup="firstToUpperCase1();" value="">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>

</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function desgCheck()
            {
                var locationName = document.getElementById('locationName').value;


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../designation/locationName.htm",
                    data: {
                        locationName: locationName
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        if ($.trim(data) !== 'Data  available')
                        {
                            alert("This Location already exist!!");
                            document.getElementById("locationName").value = "";


                            return false;
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        document.getElementById("locationName").value = "";
                    }
                });

            }


            function firstToUpperCase1() {
                var str = document.getElementById("locationName").value;
                var a = str.toUpperCase();
                $("#locationName").val(a);
            }

            jQuery("#desgForm").validationEngine();
</script>
```